# Animating an object from its center with sine wave in three.js

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js

I am trying to replicate this effect: https://dribbble.com/shots/1754428-Wave?list=users&offset=5

I want to animate a plane's vertices simlarly to the link I've provided. I know that it's achieved using a sine wave propagation, but I can't figure out how to start the movement from the central point of the plane. Right now, I have something like this

```
(function drawFrame(ts){
  window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
  var vLength = plane.geometry.vertices.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < vLength; i++) {
    var v = plane.geometry.vertices[i];
    v.z = Math.sin(ts / 500 + (v.x * (vLength / 2)) * (v.y / (vLength / 2))) * 3 + 5;
  }
```

It works kind of OK, but notice how in the top left and bottom right corners the movement is inward, towards the centre of the plane and not outwards, as it should be. The other two corners are behaving in exactly the way I want them to be.

Here's a link to what I currently have:
http://codepen.io/gbnikolov/pen/QwjGPg

All suggestions and ideas are more then welcome!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found the function you are after it was fun!

```
(function drawFrame(ts){
  var center = new THREE.Vector2(0,0);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
  var vLength = plane.geometry.vertices.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < vLength; i++) {
    var v = plane.geometry.vertices[i];
    var dist = new THREE.Vector2(v.x, v.y).sub(center);
    var size = 5.0;
    var magnitude = 2.0;
    v.z = Math.sin(dist.length()/size + (ts/500)) * magnitude;
  }
  plane.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}());
```

The circular pattern is created by creating a point as I did above called `center`. This is where the wave originates. We calculate distance to the center point. We then `sin` the distance from the center point to create the up/down. Next we add the time `ts` to create the movement. Finally we add some variables to tweak the size of the wave.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked perfectly! Can you please explain the code involved?

Comment: Updated answer with more deets